# Grafana loki search, group by json value

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

Having the following query:

```
{container_name="dal-api"} |= `update_score_day5` | logfmt | json  score="score_service" |(score > 8)
```

I was able to retrieve all logs containing scores above 8

how can i aggregate results and present all different score values like

```
1(score value): 22(logs count)
2(score value): 14(logs count)
3(score value): 33(logs count)
```

Comment: If you can direct me to how I can I group the scores by rounded values (now i have many gauge bars with: 1.2 , 1.6 etc) , thanks!

Comment: this will probably require something like `label_format`, [`ceil`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/template_functions/#ceil) and alike, because I don't think there is a way to easy convert label to value (to use a usual ceil function) without aggregation. But this warrants a separate question here on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply some form of [aggregation over time](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/metric_queries/#log-range-aggregations), you can then use result as a metric in all the usual promQL-alike approaches.

So here, I'd recommend using `count_over_time` as over time aggregation to get the number of log entries over selected time period. And then aggregationg results over `score` with [`sum by`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/metric_queries/#built-in-aggregation-operators):

```
sum by(score) (
 count_over_time(
  {container_name="dal-api"}
  |= update_score_day5
  | logfmt
  | json score="score_service"
 [1d])
)
```